# self extracting tar archive (shell scripting)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, tar, self-extracting

I have attempted to write a shell script that creates another self extracting tar archive that is zipped and encoded in base64. I don't know where to go form here and have little to no experience in shell scripting.

As is this script creates tar archive that is zipped and encoded, but the self extracting does not work when i try to run the `./tarName` from the terminal. Any advice is appreciated

```
#!/bin/sh
tarName=$1;

if [ -e $tarName.tar.gz ] 

    then /bin/echo "$tarName already exists" 
    exit 0
fi

shift;
for files;
do
    tar -czvf tmpTarBall.tar.gz $files;
done

echo "#!/bin/sh" >> $tarName.tar.gz;
echo "base64 -d $tarName.tar.gz"  >> $tarName.tar.gz;
echo "tar -xzvf $tarName.tar.gz" >> $tarName.tar.gz;
chmod +x ./$tarName.tar.gz;

base64 tmpTarBall.tar.gz >> $tarName.tar.gz;
rm tmpTarBall.tar.gz;
```

----------UPDATE

Did some looking around and this is what I have now, still doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
#!/bin/sh
tarName=$1;

if [ -e $tarName.tar.gz ] 

    then /bin/echo "$tarName already exists" 
    exit 0
fi

shift;
for files;
do
    tar -czvf tmpTarBall.tar.gz $files;
done

cat > extract.sh;
echo "#!/bin/sh" >> extract.sh;
echo "sed '0,/^#TARBALL#$/d' $0 | $tarName.tar.gz | base64 -d | tar -xzv; exit 0" >> extract.sh;
echo "#TARBALL#" >> extract.sh;

cat extract.sh tmpTarBall.tar.gz > $tarName.tar.gz;
chmod +x ./$tarName.tar.gz;

rm extract.sh tmpTarBall.tar.gz;
```

When I try to run the tarName.tar.gz i get errors:
./tarName.tar.gz: 2: ./tarName.tar.gz: tarName.tar.gz: not found
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: `exit 1` when something goes wrong — `exit 0` indicates success.  You should replace the `for` loop with just `tar -czvf tmpTarBall.tar.gz "$@"` to put all the files into a tarball.  The `c` option creates a tar file each time; you have stored only the last file listed, therefore.

Comment: You need to think carefully about what the generated shell script should look like, because that will determine what your shell script must do to create it.  Your current proposed command line is dubious on many counts, not least because you can't pipe data through a gzipped tar file in the ordinary course of events.  On the whole, you should probably use the `-b num` option to set a line length on the encoded output from `base64` (that's correct on Mac OS X; there's a chance the GNU version uses a different option).

Comment: Don't repeatedly write redirects.  Instead of `cmd1 > name; cmd2 >> name; cmd3 >> name`, write either `exec > name; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3` or `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; } > name`

Answer (score 2):

#### Desired output

In outline, the script you want to generate should look like:

```
base64 -d <<'EOF' | tar -xzf -
…base-64 encoded data…
EOF
```

The `base64` command decodes its standard input, which is provided as a here document terminated by a line containing just `EOF`.  The output is written to
`tar` with options to extract gzipped data read from standard input.

#### Minimal script

So, a minimal generator script looks like:

```
echo "base64 -d <<'EOF' | tar -czf -"
tar -czf - "$@" | base64 -w 72
echo "EOF"
```

This echoes the `base64 … | tar …` line, then uses `tar` to generate on standard output a zipped tar file containing the files or directories named on the command line, and the output is piped to the GNU coreutils version of `base64` with the option to specify that output lines should be 72 characters wide (plus the newline).  This is all followed by `EOF` to mark the end of the here document.

You can add shebang lines (`#!/bin/sh`) to either or both scripts.  There's no need to choose a more specific shell; this uses only core shell scripting constructs that would work back to the days of yore — before POSIX was a gleam in anyone's eye.

#### Possible complications

Complications that are possible include support for Mac OS X `base64` which has a usage message like this:

```
Usage:  base64 [-dhvD] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -D, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

The `-v` option and the `-d` option both generate `base64: invalid option -- v` (for the appropriate letter), plus the usage.  There doesn't seem to be a way to get version information from it.  However, GNU's `base64` does generate a useful message when you request `base64 --version`.  The first line of standard output will contain something like:

```
base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Simon Josefsson.
```

This is written to standard output.  So, you could auto-detect whether you have the GNU `base64` and adapt accordingly.  You'd need one test in the generator script, and a copy of the test in the generated script. That's definitely a more refined program.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to do this yourself?  There is an existing tool called [makeself](https://github.com/megastep/makeself) that can do this for you.  If you do need to write this yourself, here are some thoughts:

Your output file is an archive with a shell script stuck to the front of it.  The extract process runs the *entire* output file through `base64` and `tar`, not just the archive.  The `base64` call turns the script portion into garbage, which then confuses `tar`.  What you need to do is to add some code that will separate the script from the archive, then run the remaining commands on just the archive portion.  One possible way to do this is to tweak your extract script to something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
linenum=$(grep -n "__END_OF_SCRIPT_MARKER__" $tarName.tar.gz | tail -1 | sed -e 's/:.*//')
tail -n +$(($linenum + 1)) $tarName.tar.gz | base64 -d | tar -xzv
exit 0
__END_OF_SCRIPT_MARKER__
```

Make sure there is *nothing* in the script portion following the marker text except a newline character (which the markup on this website doesn't make visible).  With this, you're using `grep` to find the line number that contains the marker, then stripping off that many lines with `tail`.  What remains will be the archive portion, which is processed normally by the rest of your code.  The `exit` line ensures that the shell doesn't try to execute the marker text or the archive contents as code.  You can keep the extract code in a less compressed format if you'd rather, but you'll end up having to create a temporary file for the archive portion and ensure that it gets deleted.

Comment: When I try to echo this into my file not everything is included. i get: `#!/bin/sh
linenum=
tail -n +1 newTarTest.tar.gz | base64 -d | tar -xzv
exit 0
__END_OF_SCRIPT_MARKER__`

Comment: @minusila - when using echo to write the script to the output file, you need to escape special characters like "$()".  Otherwise, the shell will evaluate them before the echo happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without using base64 encoding.

You can just prefix a small header to the file that, when ran, strips itself from the file and passes it to tar. This option makes the file smaller that doing the same thing with base64. I would also argue that this option is more in the spirit of compression anyway.

This is the best that I can do and still have it function correctly:

```
dd if=$0 bs=4 skip=13 2>/dev/null | tar xavf -
exit
...raw tar file...
```

If you prefer, you can include the shebang at the beginning.

```
#!/bin/sh
dd if=$0 bs=2 skip=31 2>/dev/null | tar xavf -
exit
...raw tar file...
```

For reference, the -a option is for compression auto detection.

To actually use the snippet, run this command

```
cat headerfile data.tar.gz > data.tar.gz.self
```

There are some complications about this approach though, namely the fixed skip value. It shouldn't cause issues unless the header itself is changed.

If you decide to change the header script, you can get the new size the header file and edit the skip option used by dd.